# Double integral involving products of Fox H-functions

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems, statistical-mechanics

For physics application, I want to calculate the integral of the form

$$I(z)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}H^{1,1}_{2,2}(x)H^{1,1}_{2,2}(y)H^{1,1}_{2,2}(z+\lambda x +y)H^{1,1}_{2,2}(z-x-\lambda y) \text{ d}x\text{ d}y$$

where $H^{1,1}_{2,2}(\xi)$ denotes the Fox H-function:

$H^{1,1}_{2,2}(\xi)=H^{1,1}_{2,2} \left[ \xi \Bigg| \begin{matrix}
(1-\beta,\beta), & (1/2+\epsilon,1/2-\epsilon) \\
(0,1), & (1/2+\epsilon,1/2-\epsilon) 
\end{matrix}\right].$

Can this integral be calculated somehow analytically? Can the result be written in terms of some Fox H-function?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.